# youtube tracking you though TOR

Tags: anonymity

Recently while browsing on tor I visited a shop on google maps. Later using you tube out of tor it appeared to me a propaganda of that shop.It is something very specific so nothing about coincidences.Does then google let any residue on your computer to track you later? I appreciate your comments , many thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Any - literally **any** tracking script - it just tracking you, that's what it's built for! So it's nothing specific related to Google etc... To avoid this things to happen use a disposable VM's fully routed through Tor and **do not login** anywhere like Google unless you have to. If you've logged in - like in your regular browser using Tor - you will be tracked because Google knows that it's you and it does not care at all how exactly have you reached anything it spotted you on. To have an out-of-the-box solution for disposable VM's try using VirtualBox with a VM templates/overlays or - for an OS-wide scale - QubesOS

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply,could I ask how to achieve a"VM's fully routed through Tor ".Do you mean setting a VM and then browsing on tor throught the VM?

Comment: exactly like that!